# Reload image when running the application

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio

I have a Resource.resx in my project and it contains a lot of .png images.

For example, I have buttonA.png inside the Resource.resx and the buttonA color is blue. I want to change it into red so I create a new buttonA.png in red.
Then, I overwrite file buttonA.png in my Resources folder.

The problem is when I run the project in Visual Studio, it still shows the old buttonA.png with blue color.

My question is: Why the app still using the old button?

Comment: This is probably just VS. Have you ran your application and is the button still blue? If it still doesn't work, you might want to re-add it.

Comment: yap, the button still blue even though the button already red in Resource.resx

Comment: If you are sure you've added it to the .resx and it still doesn't work, consider restarting VS or even your whole device. I do not know much about the caching of VS but your problem might be there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are not including your button through solution explorer after you delete the old one. If you need to do this, please add item via solution explorer.

```
 Go To> SolutionExplorer>ShowAllFiles>RightClick the buttonA.png and IncludeInProject.
```

Comment: I don't delete the old one, so I still have it in the Resource.resx

Comment: @currarpickt May be your button is not refreshed in visual studio. The only solution is to refresh the item or include in visualstudio via solution explorer

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a caching problem. Try this;

1) Delete `toolbox*.tbd` from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`

2) Delete `devenv.CTM` from `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\1033`

Resource: [here](http://blog.hackingonhacks.com/2012/09/10/how-to-clear-the-visual-studio-image-cache/).

Comment: it's not working too. I tried to rebuild the project and it's work. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Wait... are you saying it's working after a rebuild or was that a typo?

Comment: So, when I overwrite the image in the Resource folder, it will take several seconds for Resource.resx to reload the new image. But, even though the .resx file load the new image successfully, when I run the project, the app still using the old image.

So I tried to use your solution by deleting toolbox*.tbd and devenv.CTM but still not working.

Then I tried to rebuild the project. After rebuild it several times, the app start to use the new image.